# Set background color for div in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

I've image need code css:

[image]

And here my html

```
<div class="row dvMarTop1">
                <div class="col-sm-6" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-7" >
                            <img src="images/img230.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color: #f1f1f1;">
                            <div>
                                <div>Tiêu điểm</div>
                                <div>Mark Zuckerberg thất vọng vì vệ tinh 200 triệu USD bị tên lửa SpaceX thiêu rụi</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row dvMarTop1" style="background-color:#fff">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <img src="http://imgur.com/79u89Sj" class="img-responsive" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">

                            <span>
                                Nghệ An: Cá chết dạt do thuyền chở cá chìm
                                <font><i class="fa fa-clock-o dvMarTop1 dvTimeItem"></i> &nbsp;20:00 | Chủ nhật, 15/06/2016</font>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

But as you see I cannot set full background for col-sm-5 and set vertical center text

Can you suggest more ? tks so much

Comment: I tried your code and everything works ok, take a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGNyWW

Comment: if you press the `F5` key you can refresh your browser page.

Comment: yes, I've edit code on https://jsfiddle.net/845mLos7/, But I want set full background on col-sm-5, <br> I want height col-sm-7 will equal col-sm-5

Answer (score 0):

Either you didn't refresh your browser page after you edited the code or you didn't place your style.css under the other CSS links in the head part of the code.

Comment: yes, I've edit code on jsfiddle.net/845mLos7, But I want set full background on col-sm-5, <br> I want height col-sm-7 will equal col-sm-5